# JPA AttributeConverter comparison?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, date-format

I'm looking for an easy way to query a database column of type string in format YYYYMMDD. This could be done with a native query like:

```
select * from TPRODUCT where to_date(ENDOFPRODUCTION, 'YYYYMMDD') > CURRENT_DATE;
```

But is there a way to achieve this comparison with an `AttributeConverter`

```
@NamedQuery(name = "product.filterByEOP", query =
    "select p from Product p where p.eop > :currentDate")
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out you can. In case anyone else is looking into this, after checking [the reference](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/) I ended up with:

```
public class DateConverter implements AttributeConverter<Date, String> {

    private final String DATE_FORMAT = "YYYYMMDD";

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Date date) {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT).format(date);
    }

    @Override
    public Date convertToEntityAttribute(String dateString) {
        Date converted = null;
        try {
            converted = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT).parse(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
        }
        return converted;
    }
}
```

which you can then use on an entity attribute:

```
@Column(name = "ENDOFPRODUCTION")
@Convert(converter = DateConverter.class)
private Date eop;
```

and use the query:

```
final TypedQuery<Product> query = this.entityManager.createNamedQuery("product.filterByEOP", Product.class);
query.setParameter("currentDate", new Date());
List<Product> models = query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't convert your String to a date and use this last like it is :

```
String myDate = "20170607";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMDD");
Date newDate = format.parse(myDate);
```

Now you can use :

```
query.setParameter("currentDate", newDate);
```